# Странное поведение fork() в C

Tags: c, fork

Всем здравствуйте, мне нужно создать N потоков, которые будут выполнять определённый код, поэтому я написал это:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 2

void create_threads() {
    int count = 0, result;
    printf("Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...\n");
    while ((result = fork()) != 0) {
        count++;
        if (result == -1)
            printf("Не удалось создать дополнительный поток (#%d)!\n", count);
        else if (count == N)
            return;
        printf("Создание дополнительного потока (#%d)...\n", count + 1);
    }
    // Код дополнительного потока
}
int main() {
    printf("main()\n");
    create_threads();
}
```

Но с этим кодом происходит что-то странное... Вот вывод в консоль:

```
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
```

Почему функция main() вызывается ещё два раза? Почему при втором вызове создался только один поток? Как это исправить?

P.s. Компилятор GCC 7.4.0, аргументы компиляции:

```
-Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -o a.out source_file.c
```

UDP: Изменил количество создаваемых потоков с 2 на 4 (**#define N 4**), всё равно странный вывод, но видна какая-та последовательность:

```
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#3)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#3)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#4)...
main()
Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#3)...
Создание дополнительного потока (#4)...
```

UDP 2: По совету из комментариев добавил во все сообщения результат функции getpid():

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 2

void create_threads() {
    int count = 0, result;
    printf("[%d] Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...\n", getpid());
    while ((result = fork()) != 0) {
        count++;
        if (result == -1)
            printf("[%d] Не удалось создать дополнительный поток (#%d)!\n", getpid(), count);
        else if (count == N)
            return;
        printf("[%d] Создание дополнительного потока (#%d)...\n", getpid(), count + 1);
    }
    // Код дополнительного потока
}
int main() {
    printf("[%d] main()\n", getpid());
    create_threads();
}
```

Вывод:

```
[31574] main()
[31574] Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
[31574] main()
[31574] Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
[31574] Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
[31574] main()
[31574] Создание дополнительного потока (#1)...
[31574] Создание дополнительного потока (#2)...
```

Comment: Для создания потоков вызывайте `pthread_create`

Comment: @user7860670, Почему именно эта функция? Разве она встроена в стандартную библиотеку C? Что насчёт моих вопросов по поводу этой странности?

Comment: Потому что эта функция создает *потоки*. А `fork` создает *процессы*. И ни та, ни другая, не входят в стандартную библиотеку C

Comment: Вы в Windows работаете?

Comment: функция `fork` *в переводе вилка* создаёт **не** поток, а **копию** процесса. И эти процессы размножаются.

Comment: ОС, где вы наблюдаете такое поведение fork-а напишите (`"Как это исправить?"` -- внимательно прочесть man fork и SEE ALSO в нем)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в Linux

Comment: @alexGlebe мне нужна именно копия, а насчёт того что создаётся копия процесса, а не потока, не знал. Но почему раньше когда я использовал fork не вызывался main()? И почему после второго вызова вывелось только одно сообщение о создании потока (процесса)?

Comment: @avp Linux, я читал когда-то давно, но хорошо, загляну туда опять

Comment: Заапустил ваш пример. Всё работает. Ищите проблему в конфигурации. Вы или не то компилируете, или не то заппускаете.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я о том же, раньше подобного не было)

Comment: при проверки `fork() != 0` вроде-бы должно всё линейно запускать процессы, значит в вашем дополнительном коде, которые вы не показали портится память и происходит неопределённое поведение.

Comment: @AlexGlebe там нет никакого кода) Я заранее написал комментарий чтобы не перепутать место где будет код создаваемых потоков, а во время тестирования обнаружил что происходит что-то странное

Comment: Я бы посоветовал с целью прояснения ситуации *`" а во время тестирования обнаружил что происходит что-то странное "`* во всех сообщениях печатать еще и `getpid()` (и добавить печать в main после вызова `create_threads();`)

Comment: @avp, добавил получившийся код и вывод в вопрос...

Comment: Добавьте fflush(stdout) сразу после каждого printf-a

Comment: @avp, во первых, я обнаружил что в одном месте перепутал порядок аргументов printf (из-за чего в квадратных скобках был номер потока, а в круглых его pid), во вторых, это помогло, можете написать это как ответ чтобы я отметил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо печать проводится в pipe или файл, поэтому stdout становится не linebuffered, т.е. реальный вывод из буфера при столь малом количестве печати происходит при закрытии stdout в конце работы процесса.

В результате мы видим множественный вывод буфера stdout, который в начале был заполнен в родительском процессе, а после fork унаследовался в дочерних.

Для исправления достаточно вызывать fflush(stdout) перед fork().